# How to position input and p element such that their centers match each other

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I want the element #1 and #2 to have center matching against each other. I want element 1 and 2 center (mid point) to match. How do I achieve this using css?

```
 <input id="inputCustomer" tyep="text">
 <p id="spandiv">{{customerName}}</p>
```

First element is input box and second element is p element, that appears when I hover over the input element.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `margin: 0 auto;`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align:center`

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <input id="inputCustomer" type="text">
</div>
<p id="spandiv" style="text-align:center">Customer name</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

1. have the `<input>` display as a `block` and provide a left and right `margin` of `auto`
2. have the `<p>` align its text in the `center`, since the width (by default) is `100%`.

```css
.wrapper > input {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.wrapper > p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input id="inputCustomer" tyep="text">
  <p id="spandiv">{{customerName}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code snippet, this might be useful:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

li p {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50px
  background-color: #FFF;
}

li:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="text" />
    <p>Text to show</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```